# SVG: rect is always behind line

Tags: html, svg, line, rect

I am creating a sample stock chart using svg and I am having trouble getting the rect elements to be on top of the line elements.  Everything I have read says they simply need to be added to the SVG first. However, that isn't doing the trick.

How do I get the rect to appear on top of the lines?

Here is whats being displayed:

[image]

Here is what the Html looks like:

```html
<svg height="110" width="105">
  <rect width="5" height="28" x="7.5" y="22" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:red"></rect>
  <rect width="5" height="12" x="27.5" y="49.5" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:red"></rect>
  <rect width="5" height="39" x="47.5" y="22" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:white"></rect>
  <rect width="5" height="7" x="67.5" y="22" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:red"></rect>
  <line x1="0" y1="35.6666666666667" x2="20" y2="30" style="stroke:limegreen; stroke-width:4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="22" x2="20" y2="49.5" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:4"></line>
  <line x1="20" y1="30" x2="40" y2="35.3333333333333" style="stroke:limegreen; stroke-width:4"></line>
  <line x1="20" y1="49.5" x2="40" y2="61" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:4"></line>
  <line x1="40" y1="35.3333333333333" x2="60" y2="41.6666666666667" style="stroke:limegreen; stroke-width:4"></line>
  <line x1="40" y1="61" x2="60" y2="22" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:4"></line>
  <line x1="60" y1="41.6666666666667" x2="80" y2="46.6666666666667" style="stroke:limegreen; stroke-width:4"></line>
  <line x1="60" y1="22" x2="80" y2="29" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:4"></line>
 </svg>
```

Comment: To be on top stuff needs to be last. Painter's model: What you paint last is on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert Longson's comment is correct: what you paint last (i.e. what is nearer the end of the svg file/element) is on the top of the image.

I simplified your image and showed two different scenarios, one with the rectangle on the bottom, one with the rectangle on the top. In each case, the element that comes last in the SVG file is the one on "top" of the image.

```html
<div>
  black & white rectangle is first in SVG element & is on "bottom" of image
  <div>
    <svg height="90" width="105">
      <rect width="5" height="39" x="47.5" y="22" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:white"></rect>
      <line x1="40" y1="61" x2="60" y2="22" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:4"></line>
    </svg>
  </div>
  black & white rectangle is last in SVG element & is on "top" of image
  <div>
    <svg height="90" width="105">
      <line x1="40" y1="61" x2="60" y2="22" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:4"></line>
      <rect width="5" height="39" x="47.5" y="22" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:white"></rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```